# mathtools package - Package database exclusively locked

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I’m having an issue concerning the mathtools package.
I’m using MikTex 2.9 and TexMaker. Whenever I attempt to run the following example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
    
\begin{document}
This is a test.  
\end{document}
```

I get this error message:

> Another MiKTeX program has exclusevily locked the package database.

This is the info I obtained from the consoles error log via the 'Copy Info' Button:

```
GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION ReportDate: 2021-04-12 06:04:57
CurrentVersion: 21.3 SetupDate: 2018-04-26 20:38:00
SetupVersion: 2.9
Configuration: Regular
GitInfo: ab8ebca / 2021-03-19 10:22:46
OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 19042
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9
Root3: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
UserInstall: C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Invokers: .../explorer/A43/texmaker

ERROR DETAILS
Program: pdflatex
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageManagerImpl.cpp:119
Error: The package database is locked and cannot be accessed.
Description: Another MiKTeX program has exclusevily locked the package database.
Remedy: Close running MiKTeX programs and try again.
```

Moreover I got the notification that the file `calc.sty` could not be found and that the file in question is part of the `latex-tools` package. In addition, the console of TexMaker produces the following error message.

> C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mathtools\mathtools.sty
>
> ! LaTeX Error: File `calc.sty' not found.Type X to quit or  to
> proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:!
> Emergency stop. \RequirePackage

I checked both of the paths:

```
C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mathtools\
C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\tex/latex/latex-tools\
```

And indeed the folder `mathtools` does not contain the file `calc.sty` while the folder `latex-tools` does.

I attempted to uninstall both packages via MikTex console, then refreshed the file name database as well as the font map files and updated the package database. Then I reinstalled the packages and repeated the refreshment and updating process but to no avail. I have made sure that MikTex Console ran in Administrator mode during the procedure.

It seems that my MikTex installation is somehow unable to detect the two paths and the file `calc.sty`. Unfortunately, my Google searches have only yielded results regarding missing mathtools.sty files which is a distinct issue. So I am not sure what else can be done.

Edit: I was to able to resolve the issue by completely uninstalling and then reinstalling MikTex 2.9.

Comment: The error messages says that something locked the package database.  Do you have some application open like Yap? Did you try to close everything (also texmaker)  and compile once on a command line?

Comment: Please check if `calc.sty` is available in your MiKTeX database. Alternatively, reinstall `mathtools` package using MiKTeX Package Manager.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I did try to close everything (including texmaker) and compile everything on a command line but I got the same error as described in the post above. Also, no other applications were active at the time I encountered this error.

Comment: then ask in the miktex github.

Comment: Run Texmaker with administrator privileges. That will solve the issue (Right click then run as administrator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that package database locking appears commonly on Windows 10, I had this problem several times after some packages needed to be updated through Mik-Tex Console. The usual answer for resolving the problem on the forums is "reinstall your MikTex", which clearly is not something you want to do every other day. I still do not know the cause for this behavior, but I hope this work-around will help somebody to get rid of the issue faster:

The database unlocks once you compile your tex file directly in command prompt running it as administrator. After that, the file compiles also in your tex-editor.

Answer (score -1):

First, remove Miktex completely, including registry information. Then reinstall Miktex, remembering not to install it in folders that require administrator access, such as Program Files.

Comment: I always install MiKTeX in Program Files, and I never had any trouble with that choice.